# Couldn't setup an existing drupal site on local server

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

imported database, copied drupal site files to wamp/www folder, changed database configuration files, but got "Drupal already installed" error.

Tried by increasing packet size on mysql configuration file.While trying with an empty database , through the setup steps, site being installed. Is there any solution to use the existing database

Drupal version:8.9.20
Php: 7.4.26
apache: 2.4.51
mysql:5.7.36

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This message can happen for several different reasons, so here is a start to help you trouble shoot:

#### MySQL max_allowed_packet, innodb_buffer_pool_size, innodb_lock_wait_timeout

- Adding this to verify that this is the packet setting you updated in `my.ini`
- Try updating the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` & `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`  settings as well
- Be sure to restart MySQL after the update is made
- [drupal.org source](https://www.drupal.org/node/984112)

#### Verify Permissions `settings.local.php` & MySQL DB user

- Make sure the file permissions on your `/sites/default/` folder is correct, and `settings.local.php` file (or whichever settings file you are using)
- Make sure the DB user you have configured in the settings file has the correct permissions to the DB as well

#### Check log files

- Check all log files in your WAMP log folder to see if there is any additional information